# How do you run a standalone ijs j file on Linux?

Tags: j

I have been using `j` for a few weeks now and loving it. However, all of my work has been in the `ijconsole`. Does `j` provide a way to run `.ijs` files without using `load`? Similar to how you can simply run `$python my_file.py`?

I know for windows there exists `jconsole.exe`, but for Linux and OSx there doesn't seem to be the same option?

Comment: I work with OSx and there is certainly a jconsole available when I click on the grey J icon in the j901 folder.

Also, there is some documentation on how to create standalone applications in J8 which is the current non-beta version (beta version is j901). It looks more involved than the python example you show, but there are instructions for Linux and OSx that may get you moving in the right direction. Others with more experience may add to this comment, but that should get you started.

https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/J8_Standalone#Building_the_standalone_script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get my desired behavior from

https://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/hashbang.htm

The basic idea is to create a "unix script" that points to jconsole by using

`#!/home/fred/j64-807/bin/jconsole`

at the top of the `.ijs` file.

Then, you can `echo` any output you wish or use `ARGV` to read input.

Finally, call `chmod +x your_script.ijs` and run using `./your_script.ijs`

You can copy the j interpreter files to new projects on servers etc and call them using bash.

So, a final example would be

```
#!/home/fred/j64-807/bin/jconsole
echo +/*:0".>,.2}.ARGV
exit''
```

Which computes the sum of squares of digits from command line arguments

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to run `bin/jconsole` with the `.ijs` file as the first command line argument.

Here's an example session, copied out of my terminal:

```
~/j64-807$ cat ex.ijs 
d =: 1+1
~/j64-807$ ./bin/jconsole ex.ijs 
   d
2
```

Comment: Oh this is neat! Is there a way to duplicate this behavior without entering the `j` command line? What I mean is, is there a way to have everything happen with stdin and stdout? 

It seems like this loads the `ijs` file and then you have access to everything defined therein.

This is really neat though.